# Android Evernote like slidingMenu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, evernote

I want to design Evernote like sliding menu for my Android App that includes Gridview and Listview of content in the Sliding Menu.

[image: Evernote For Android Showing sliding menu]

I have implemented two frameLayouts in the slidingMenu layout file, one for the Gridview and other for the Listview. Here is the xml file of it.

menu_frame.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/grid_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_frame"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

List View Framelayout xml file for id:menu_frame

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

Gridview Framelayout xml file for id:grid_frame

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding">
    <!-- android:id="@+id/grid_list" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:text="Grid Layout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Finaly here is java code for slidingmenu:
SlideMenuBaseActivity.java

```
public class SlideMenuBaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity{

    private int mTitleRes;
    protected SherlockListFragment mFrag;

    protected SherlockFragment mFragGrid;

    public SlideMenuBaseActivity(int titleRes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mTitleRes = titleRes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(mTitleRes);

        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new SlidingMenuFragment();
            mFragGrid = new SlidingGridFragment();

            FragmentTransaction t2 = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            t2.replace(R.id.grid_frame, mFragGrid);
            t2.commit();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            //t.replace(R.id.grid_frame, mFragGrid);
            t.commit();
        } else {
            mFrag = (SherlockListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
            mFragGrid = (SherlockFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.grid_frame);
        }

        // customize the SlidingMenu
                SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
                sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
                sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
                sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
                sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
                sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
                 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I have implemented code as above but only grid_view content is visible on the slidingMenu but not List_view content.
Can any one please suggest me a solution to get complete view like evernote sliding menu using fragments for my app.....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using Navigation Drawer instead of Sliding Menu. 
It's more easier to achieve your goal.

Simple check those links:

[Create Navigation Drawer and See Example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

[Information](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

It's simple to use, and as you want with fragments. You can easily make custom design for Left Drawer.
For me it looks like evernote uses the same pattern.

Comment: I used Navigation drawer but it is very complicated than sliding menu library.